# Java conics calculator

Tags: java

Creating a Java calculator to determine what a conic is based on A and C. I've just barely started working in Java, haven't even finished a CodeAcademy course, so I need a bit of help debugging and rewriting this. Thank you!

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {



    System.out.println("INPUT YOUR DESIRED EQUATION IN THE FORM Ax\u00B2 + Bxy + Cy\u00B2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0"); 

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("INPUT THE VALUE OF A: ");

    int a = reader.nextInt(); 

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in

    System.out.println("INPUT THE VALUE OF C: ");

    int c = reader.nextInt(); 

    if (a = 0 || b = c) {

            System.out.println("YOUR EQUATION IS A PARABOLA");

        } else if (a = c) {

            System.out.println("YOUR EQUATION IS A CIRCLE");

        }   else if (a*c > 0) {


            System.out.println("YOUR EQUATION IS AN ELLIPSE");

        }

            else {

                System.out.println("YOUR EQUATION IS A HYPERBOLA");

            }


}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `==` in place of `=` in your conditional statements. `==` is a test for equality. `=` is the assignment operator. The way all of your conditional statements are currently written, they are assigning values to variables instead of comparing them, and, since assignment statements cannot return a boolean value, your code cannot compile.

Additionally, there is no need to declare `reader` twice. You actually can't do that. The second time it encounters this line:

`Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);`

The program has to create a NEW variable called `reader`, which it can't do because there is already an existing one with the same name. Now, it would be possible to do this the second time:

`reader = new Scanner(System.in);`

In this case, you are simply re-assigning `reader` to point to a new `Scanner` rather than attempting to create another variable.

However, doing so would be completely unnecessary, as `reader` already refers to a `Scanner` for `System.in`, so you should simply remove the second occurrence of that statement altogether.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've modified the code, but now I am getting an error Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at Ideone.main(Main.java:20) when I attempt to run it in Ideone. It will at least compile now, but is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: @synapticrelay To be honest, I can't see what could be causing that, nor can I manage to replicate it. What input are you entering?

Comment: I am unsure how to post the full code a reply to a comment; I added another "answer" and posted the updated code there

Comment: @synapticrelay Isn't that just the same code with the previous problems fixed? What is the actual input you're typing in when you run it and get that error?

Answer (score 0):

@bethany-louise

Full input, along with the Ideone default code is this (apologies if the post/reply etiquette is off in any way)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{

System.out.println("INPUT YOUR DESIRED EQUATION IN THE FORM Ax\u00B2 + Bxy + Cy\u00B2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0"); 

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("INPUT THE VALUE OF A: ");

int a = reader.nextInt(); 

System.out.println("INPUT THE VALUE OF C: ");

int c = reader.nextInt(); 

if (a == 0 || c == 0) {

    System.out.println("YOUR EQUATION IS A PARABOLA");

} else if (a == c) {

    System.out.println("YOUR EQUATION IS A CIRCLE");

}   else if (a*c > 0) {


    System.out.println("YOUR EQUATION IS AN ELLIPSE");

}

    else {

        System.out.println("YOUR EQUATION IS A HYPERBOLA");

    }
}
}
```